# Laravel: One Controller for multiple Models

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm currently rebuilding my vanilla-PHP-App with Laravel and I have the following problem.
I have multiple database-tables, that represent word categories (noun, verb, adverb, ...). For each table I created a separate Model, a route::resource and a separate resource-Controller. For example:

NomenController.php

```
public function show($id)
{
    $vocab = Nomen::find($id);
    return view('glossarium.vocab_update', compact('vocab'));
}
```

and

VerbController.php

```
public function show($id)
{
    $vocab = Verb::find($id);
    return view('glossarium.vocab_update', compact('vocab'));
}
```

...which are essentially the same except the Model class.

I don't want to create a separate Controller for each model, that does exactly the same. What would be the most simple and elegant way to solve this? 
Should I just create a VocabController.php and add a parameter for the Model-name like:

```
Route::resource('/vocab/{category}', 'VocabController');
```

and then add a constructor method in this controller like

```
public function __construct ($category) {
    if ($category == 'nomen') {
        $this->vocab = App\Nomen;
    }
    else if ($category == 'verb') {
         $this->vocab = App\Verb;
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a simpler method to do that. Can I somehow do this with Route Model Binding?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You suggested way would work, but I would suggest creating a "Vocab" model that nouns/verbs/etc inherit from, then you just need your vocab controller.

Answer (score 7):

Simply create a `trait` like this in **App\Traits**, (you can name it anything... Don't go with mine though... I feel its pretty lame... :P)

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait CommonControllerFunctions {

    public function show($id) {
        $modelObject = $this->model;

        $model = $modelObject::find($id);

        return view('glossarium.vocab_update', compact('model'));
    }

}
```

and in your **NomenController** and **VerbController**, do this:

```
use App\Traits\CommonControllerFunctions;

class NomenController {

    use CommonControllerFunctions;

    protected $model = Nomen::class;

}
```

and

```
use App\Traits\CommonControllerFunctions;

class VerbController {

    use CommonControllerFunctions;

    protected $model = Verb::class;

}
```

**Note:** Please note that this example is just a work-around for your particular situation only... Everyone practices code differently, so this method might not be approved by all...

Comment: Thank you! I will read a bit more about traits, then try it out and post about it.

Comment: This solution still doesn't solve problem with router. Developer still have to create 2 routes. Using traits for two identical controllers isn't the easiest solution ;-)

Comment: @piotr Actually, each resource route should work for one single controller only. Putting everything into one controller is a wrong practice. If one day a separate field is added to say 'Verbs' table... Then a new controller will have to be made along with a new route (anyways) and all steps will have to be repeated... Therefore, this is an invalid practice of structuring code and I myself don't approve of such coding practices that is why I wrote the last line in my answer. Each function in our code must follow single responsibility rule.

Comment: You are right, but Bene wanted as simple as possible solution

Comment: @piotr Simple it can be. Invalid it can not. I have no problems with your answer. I just shared what I feel is valid/authentic according to me. Personally, I would never follow the approach of Bene. This is not how we follow a modular structure. Every Controller must have its own view, own modal. Coding should be done in such a way that adding anything extra in the future doesn't lead to breaking changes in the code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simpliest way it to create only one controller, eg `VocabController` with methods `nomen`, `verb` and whatever you want.

Routes:

```
Route::get('/vocab/nomen/{nomen}', 'VocabController@item');
Route::get('/vocab/verb/{verb}', 'VocabController@item');
```

And the model binding:

```
Route::model('nomen', 'App\Nomen');
Route::model('verb', 'App\Varb');
```

Then your method shoud look like that:

```
public function item($item)
{
    return view('glossarium.vocab_update', $item);
}
```

Keep in mind, that `$item` is already fetched model from the database.

Comment: Hmm looks interesting. If I have a Controller method for each database table, would I then need separate methods for the CRUD-Operations like      public function verb_create,.... public function verb_delete, nomen_create, nomen_delete, etc... ? Or do I just have to write different routes for each request (like PUT, DELETE, etc...) ?

Comment: I think that the separate routes are better